# Get-RDUserSession - Not returning anything for one Collection

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, windows-server-2019

If I run `Get-RDUserSession` From two of my three RDP Servers I get what I expect. If I run it in a third collection I get nothing, It takes it sweet time, but just returns to the command line.  All three Server Collections are Win2019.

I can run the commands with the specific collection info with the same results

```
 Get-RDUserSession -CollectionName <collection1-name> -ConnectionBroker <broker1>
 Get-RDUserSession -CollectionName <collection2-name> -ConnectionBroker <broker2>
 Get-RDUserSession -CollectionName <collection3-name> -ConnectionBroker <broker3>
```

The third does not return data. I’m Logged into it, so I know there is a user on.  Running with `Get-RDUserSession -verbose -debug`

```
 PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-RDUserSession -verbose -debug

VERBOSE: No user sessions were found matching the specified criteria.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the TerminalServices-SessionBroker-Client Event Log, I found the Following:

```
Remote Desktop Services failed to join the Connection Broker on server <original-ConnectionBroker>.
Error: Current async message was dropped by async dispatcher, because there is a new message which will override the current one.
```

`<original-ConnectionBroker>` was the Session-Host that was the First/Only Session-Host in the Collection when it was Created.

We added / and removed  Some time ago.   It looks like it was still trying to access  for the Session Connections when the user logs in.

So to Fix this, I removed `<session-host3>` from the Collection. So no more Session Hosts in the Collection. Then Added `<session-host3>` back to the Collection. That Showed the Connection is the Collection again and then the `Get-RDUserSession` worked again and retuned the proper session connections.